# Connecting a 1280x720 Laptop to a high resolution screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have connected my laptop (which has 1280x720 resolution) to my Samsung's 4k screen.

I chose my Samsung's screen as the `Main display`. I am not mirroring/extending the displays.

The windows-7 suggested to choose the 1920x1080 resolution but with that resolution, the whole screen/desktop/windows are not visible.

What should I do so that I can see properly sized windows on my Samsung's screen?

**PS:** I am running windows 7

Comment: What is the objective of connecting the TV to the laptop? If you extend your display the problem will go away

Comment: I even tried to extend my display but the problem remains same.

Comment: I am assuming you are connecting via HDMI? Perhaps a driver issue? If you set your computer to mirror does your laptop screen show anything and TV not, or do they both not show anything?

Comment: Yes I am connecting via Hdmi. If I mirror then both the screen displays same content but the Samsung screen show content only in little area (which make sense since it has higher resolution than laptop screen). In the mirror mode, the content on Samsung's screen is strecthed and not visible on the edges.

Comment: TVs are not computer monitors, and still overscan (by upscaling and cropping) even though it may not be necessary.  You need to read your owner's/user manual, and learn how to choose the image size/zoom/no-zoom.

Comment: Are you sure your laptop supports higher resolutions?